# flip svg upside-down and rightside-left

Tags: python, svg

Given the location of the shape doesn't matter, is there a built-in python function that allow us to flip the svg path? Or could we do it by adjusting the svg values?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the SVG via a transform attribute.

```
transform="scale(-1, -1)"
```

should do it.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I should've specified more. I want to get a new svg path. E.g. If i'm given a path like <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />, i'd like to get something similar to <path d="M150 0 L300 0 L225 200 Z"/>. Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to write the code for that yourself. Good luck with that endeavour. I don't see why you'd bother though given the simplicity of using a transform instead.

Comment: @RobertLongson To avoid spending extra resources for rendering the transform. Wont seem much when just about one SVG in a browser, but might mean something when dealing with complex and numerous SVGs that are rendered not necessarily by a browser.